# Book about biochemistry for physicist

Tags: biochemistry, books

I want to understand the basics of biochemistry, from a physicist point of view. I am looking for a textbook that discusses things like the covalent bond and the oxidation number, starting from first principles (quantum mechanics), and builds up to explain things like why ATP is an energetic currency of metabolism, the organization of glycolysis, and oxidative phosphorylation. Of course I do not expect to have detailed mathematical derivations of all of these. But I do want to end up with a firm grasp of the physical principles involved.

Maybe there is single textbook covering these areas, so I would also appreciate suggestions to build a "reading-list", which can include classic papers.

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense. There is no physicist point of view in biochemistry. It's a chemical view of biology. There is no physical model capable of capturing the complexities here in a useful and familiar way. There's a reason chemistry is its own discipline, and not just physics.

Comment: @Zhe I disagree. There are many books tackling even more complex problems from a physical perspective. By this I mean that the discussion always carries the relevant physical principles  to the forefront and involves quantiative models. An example is the book Phillips, R., et al. Physical Biology of the Cell, which deals with very complex topics like signalling, protein folding, etc., but always maintaining the "physicist perspective". Do you see what I mean?

Comment: There are many possible books those that come to mind are  'Protein Physics' by  Finkenstein & Ptitsyn (publ AP), 'Applied Biophysics' by Waigh (publ Wiley), 'Molecular & Cellular Biophysics' by Jackson (publ Cambridge) & 'Molecular Biophysics' by Daune, (publ Oxford).

Comment: There is no way for you, for example, to capture the concept of nucleophilicity from a physical perspective. At some point, you've left physics behind to discuss chemistry. Physics is good at describing simple systems and aggregate systems (frankly, just like chemistry). But chemistry ignores the smallest scales to build abstractions of intermediate size systems that physicists don't care about. You asked about biochemistry. To ignore the chemistry and rely so heavily on physics means that you're not looking at biochem. It's either physics or biophysics.

Comment: @Zhe Why do you say that nucleophilicity cannot be captured from a physical perspective? There should be at least a simple example or model system where a discussion can be given in terms of the quantum mechanical principles involved.

Comment: Because it's inherently a chemical concept. If you feel that everything can be captured from a physical perspective, then I challenge you to explain an elephant from it. Even if you were able to, I think the insights you derive would not be the ones you were most interested in. There's nothing wrong with the physical perspective. It's just not the appropriate (or even feasible) lens to approach every problem.

Comment: @Zhe There are papers that calculate the nucleophilicity from first principles and numerical computations (ex. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp105914c). This means that the quantum mechanics principles involved can be stated precisely enough. I'd suspect that there are textbooks explaining the principles involved in an accessible manner. Probably some simple example, like an hydrogen atom or an approximate model of a larger atom, can even be solved analytically in some form. I am only trying to describe the intent of what I am looking for.

Comment: If you focus on the physics too much, you're going to miss the important features of the other discipline, in this case, chemistry or biology or their interplay. Those features don't have a physicist point of view. As someone who has studied both chemistry and physics, my warning to you is this: don't fall into that trap.

Comment: @Zhe Thanks. I don't want to miss those features. I am already studying books on biochemistry (such as Lehninger) which I think offer this perspective you mention. It's the physical aspect that I am lacking (specially since I am a physicist by training) and would like to read more about it

Comment: Physicists normally do not understand that chemistry in general and organic chemistry in particular is very empirical and has rules that are based loosely on ideas, for example, about charges being here and there in a molecule and reacting in this way or that. These rules  are based primarily on a vast amount of experimental data as the effects are subtle and cannot be easily computed with current technology. In proteins the situation is somewhat easier, only 20 amino acids, limited geometry of reaction site, seen via xray  diffraction,  and so on, so these are  more easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

Your question will probably get closed because any answer is going to be an opinion. Instead of recommending a book-I'll shed a little light on what your journey will be like.

#### The Subject(s)

Your pursuit to describe high level biological functionalities using first principals covers many fields. I don't think you'll find a single book that explains it all. Instead, you're going to have to learn from a number of different sources.

1. [Physical Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_chemistry) - This will give an overview of electronic structure using quantum mechanics
2. [Physical Organic Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_organic_chemistry) - Learn how to apply physical chemistry to organic molecules.
3. [Bio-Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemistry) - Apply organic chemistry to biological processes.
4. [Physical Bio-Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_biochemistry) Combines physical chemistry with bio chemistry.

You're really after point 4, but it will need to learn a fair amount before getting there.

#### The Reality

The reality of things is that we don't need to dig down to first principals to describe many biological processes. Chemistry is able to abstract enough of the nitty-gritty away to come up with easier & faster high level concepts.

Take programming for example, web developers don't need to write websites in assembly language because someone has gone ahead and abstracted it all into a nice user friendly language. You could spend a lifetime coding a site like stackexchange in assembly-or you could use a higher level language and do it in a few months.

Just how you won't find a book on website design using assembly language (first principals), you probably won't be finding one describing biology using pure quantum mechanics.

#### Further Steps

Assess your current knowledge of physical and (general) chemistry. Once you know which level you're at, go to different university sites and check which books the professors are using to teach. If you find a course that is covering the topics that you're interested in-contact the TA or professor and ask for recommendations; I'm sure they'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks. If you can suggest some specific books that would be great, or at least University Departments websites that offer these kind of courses.